# Program type already present: org.kxml2.wap.wml.Wml

Tags: android, gradle

i'm getting an error making a project **rebuild**:

> Program type already present: org.kxml2.wap.wml.Wml

I'm using [ksoap2-android-assembly](http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/getting-started) and a module ExKsoap2 from [easywdsl](https://easywsdl.com/Home/Faq). I'm also using two libraries **.aar**, and one of them is using the class named above: `org.kxml2.wap.wml.Wml`

I tried to exclude the group/module in the implementation of the `ExKsoap2` module, but the error persists.

**UPDATE:** here is my build.gradle (dependency section) :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])

    implementation 'de.mindpipe.android:android-logging-log4j:1.0.3'
    implementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

    // kotlin library
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // librerias .jar
    implementation(project(':ExKsoap2')) {
        exclude module: "org.kxml2.wap"
    }

    // libreria de zytrust
    implementation project(':zylib')

    // multidex
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:${multidex_v}"

    // simple-xml
    implementation('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }

    // support library
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${support_library_v}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${recyclerview_library_v}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${support_library_v}"

    // google play services
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${play_services_v}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${play_services_v}"

    // retrofit
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofit_v}") {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }

    // adapter-rxjava
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:${retrofit_v}") {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }

    // converter-gson
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofit_v}") {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }

    // logging-interceptor
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${logging_interceptor_v}") {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }

    // rxjava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${rxandroid_v}"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${rxjava_v}"

    // apache commons: collections
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${apachecommons_lang_v}"

    // butterknife
    implementation("com.jakewharton:butterknife:${butterknife_v}") {
        exclude module: 'support-compat'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${butterknife_v}"

    // dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${dagger_v}"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${dagger_v}"

    // view-model
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:${lifecycle_version}"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:${lifecycle_version}"

    // calligraphy
    implementation "uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:${calligraphy_v}"

    // room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:${room_v}"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:${room_v}"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_v"

    // stetho
    implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:${stetho_version}"

    // leakcanary
    debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:${leakcanary_v}"
    releaseImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${leakcanary_v}"
    debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-support-fragment:${leakcanary_v}"

}
```

Comment: Could you please port your gradle file as well.

Comment: Hi ! I updated the question with the dependency section.